# Expected decay time with uniformly distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> A strange radioactive sample initially contains $N>1$ atoms. Each day, if the sample contains $m$ atoms, then it decays in such a way that at the end of the day, the number of atoms remaining is uniformly distributed over $\{1,\dots,m-1\}$. Let $X_k$ be the number of atoms left at the end of day $k$ (with $X_0=N$). Define $T=\min\{k\geq0\mid X_k=1\}$. What is $\mathbb E[T]$?

Clearly the $X_k$ form a Markov Chain. I can write down the transition probabilities as $p_{ij}=\frac{1}{i-1}$ if $1\leq j\leq i-1$, else $p_{ij}=0$. However, I'm not sure how to find $\mathbb E[T]$. Certainly, $T<N$. Further, since in expectation the number of atoms halves each day, we might expect intuitively that $\mathbb E[T]$ will be $O(\log N)$, but this of course is not at all a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k_i=\mathbb E[T\mid X_0=i]$. Then for $n>2$, we have
\begin{align}
k_n &= 1+\frac{1}{n-1}(k_2+\dots+k_{n-1}) \\
k_{n-1} &= 1+\frac{1}{n-2}(k_2+\dots+k_{n-2}).
\end{align}
So from the second equation, $k_2+\dots+k_{n-2}=(n-2)(k_{n-1}-1)$. Sticking this into the first,
$$k_n=1+\frac{1}{n-1}[(n-1)k_{n-1}-(n-2)]=k_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Now with $k_2=1$ and $k_3=1+\frac{1}{2}$, it follows inductively that
$$\mathbb E[T]=k_N=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{i}.$$
As you suspected, this is indeed $O(\log N)$.