# Expected time to to reach a state in a MC

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

There is a Markov chain that moves on the integers from 1 to $n$, starting from 1.
At every jump, the process, decides to move to another state bigger than the one where it currently is with uniform probability, meaning that if I have $k$ different possible states to chose from, each will have the same chance $\frac{1}{k}$.
What is the expected time to reach state $n$? And what happens if $n$ goes to infinity?

I have been able to demonstrate that the expected time is always bounded, but I really have a difficult time to find a real rule to calculate it for a fixed value of $n$.

Comment: Let $T$ be the number of steps it takes to get to state $n$. For each $j\in \{1,.\ldots ,n\}$ set $$a_j=\mathbb{E}(T|X_0=j)$$ You need to find $a_1$. Did you try this approach yet? You can use the total law of expectation by conditioning on $X_1$ to develop a recursive formula for $a_j$

Comment: [This problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969359/304635) is equivalent: instead of starting at $1$, making uniform jumps to bigger numbers, in the linked question you start at $n$ and make uniform jumps to smaller numbers.

Comment: This is an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).  If you apply the formula for expected time to absorption to a few small examples, you will quickly guess the general formula, and easily confirm it.

Comment: @jlammy Thanks! So if I'm not mistaken the expected time goes to infinity when $n$ does? It would seem so from the problem you are referring to, but it would mean I messed something up in my reasoning (it wouldn't be surprising though). Thanks also for the other two replies, you guys are right too.