# Cut a number to a random integer between 0 and that number. Keep going until that number is 0. How many cuts do we need?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Start with an integer like *n = 100* and set it equal to a uniformaly random integer between **[0,n]** inclusive. Keep cutting it this way until *n = 0*. What's the expected value of the number of cuts needed?

For me, intuition gives an expected value of $\log_2 n ≈ 6.64$, but empirical simulation in Python:

```
import random
 
cuts = 0
expectedValue = 0
trials = 100000
 
for i in range(trials):
  startingValue = 100
  while startingValue > 0:
    startingValue = random.randint(0, startingValue)
    cuts += 1
 
expectedValue = cuts / trials
print(expectedValue)
```

results in $≈6.18$.

Does there exist an explicit solution for *n = 100* or for any integer *n*?

Comment: What is your intuitive reasoning for why it must be $\log_2(n)$. You are more likely to get an answer if you explain your reasoning.

Comment: @PhysMath That would apply if each cut divided the number in half. That is 100->50->25 and so on.

Comment: Why not derive an iterative formula for expectation $E_n$ and run *that* through Python? I think the formula is something like $E_n=1+\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n E_i$ (which, when solved for $E_n$, gives $E_n=1+\frac{1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E_i}{n}$), with $E_0=0$.

Comment: I don't think the disagreement between the calculation and your intuition is large enough to be significant.  It probably comes from large drops that speed you up more than small drops slow you down.

Comment: I've implemented my idea myself, and got expectation $6.187377517639617$, which is $\log_{2.1049351567370875}100$. What is weirder, as $n$ grows, so does the base. E.g. for $n=10^6$ I get $15.392726722866213=\log_{2.4535475887579854}n$, which fuels my suspicion that, for really big $n$ the expectation may behave like $\ln n$, rather than $\log_2 n$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: This is actually pretty cool! Rather naive question: why from a conceptual standpoint it should be $\ln n$? It really should be $\log_2 n$, right? On general grounds, if we have no access to simulation, how do we pick between the two? Should we pick $\ln n$ because for 'analytical' reasons, typically is the one that works best (i.e., is neater) when from a conceptual standpoint it should be $\log_2 n$?

Comment: This problem is the same as the frog problem, see ["The Frog Problem (puzzle in YouTube video)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427165/the-frog-problem-puzzle-in-youtube-video)

You can solve this with a recurrence relation. The expected number of steps when we are in position $n$ is equal to $1$ plus the mean of the expected number of steps from $0$ to $n$.

$$E_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n E_k$$

which has [as solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/427430/164061) for $n \geq 1$

$$E_n = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: @Kolmin If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{E_n}$ exists, *that* limit is what we need to pick, and it is not $2$. I don't know if it is $e$. May be something else. (**Update**: Just reading the answer below, it *is* $e$.) In other words, the base being $2$ is the "good story" that the truth that the base is *actually* $e$ *should* get in the way of, despite [what Mark Twain once said](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/807622-never-let-the-truth-get-in-the-way-of-a).

Comment: Essentially a reformulation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969359/304635)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If $\ e_n\ $ is the expected number of cuts to reach $\ \{0\}\ $ from $\ \bigcup_\limits{i=0}^n\{i\}\ $, then $\ e_n\ $ satisfies the recursion
\begin{align}
e_0&=0\\
e_n&=1+\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{e_i}{n+1}\ .
\end{align}
It's not difficult${}^\dagger$ to show by induction that the solution of this recursion is given by
$$
e_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}
$$
for $\ n\ge1\ $. As is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\ln n\right)=\gamma\ $, where $\ \gamma\approx0.57722\ $ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), so therefore $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(e_n-\ln n\right)=\gamma+1\ $, and
$$
e_n\approx1+\gamma+\ln n
$$
for sufficiently large $\ n $. For $\ n=100\ $ this gives
\begin{align}
e_{100}&\approx1.57722+\ln100\\
&\approx6.1824
\end{align}
in good agreement with the result of your python simulation.

${}^\dagger$ Especially if you use the observation made by TheBestMagician in a comment below.

**Addendum**

According to [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=sum+from+i%3D1+to+100+of+Power%5Bi%2C-1%5D)  the exact value of $\ e_{100}\ $ rounded to $20$ significant figures is $$\color{green}{6.1873775176396}\color{red}{202608},$$which agrees with the value obtained by Stinking Bishop to its $13^\text{th}$ decimal place.

Comment: The way I found the closed form is writing $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$, then using $e_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$. This substitution is pretty natural given the recurrence.

Comment: Nice. I'm now kicking myself for not having noticed this.

Comment: For the union in the definition of $e_n$, why does the counting variable start at 1? It obviously makes no difference to start at 0, as that just adds a 0 term to the sum which we can then ignore, but it still seems to me that cutting e.g $\{1,2,3\}$ can never result in $\{0\}$, at least the way I would interpret the cutting operation.

Comment: It started at $1$ because I boobed.  Thanks for picking up the error,  which I've now fixed.

Comment: Excellent, brilliant answer (+1)! BTW my Python code only used the double-precision floating point, so it is about expected to produce the result as accurate as it did. I did it just as a test whether the OP's original result was widely off the mark due to the way they did it (using Monte Carlo, with $100,000$ iterations).

Answer (score 5):

This problem is similar to the Frog problem, see the description on cross validated ["The Frog Problem (puzzle in YouTube video)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427165/the-frog-problem-puzzle-in-youtube-video) and this variant [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/427430/164061).

The short form of the recurrence relationship can alternatively also be seen more directly by

$$e_n = \underbrace{\frac{1}{n+1} (e_n+1)}_{\text{remain in same place}} +  \underbrace{\frac{n}{n+1} (e_{n-1})}_{\text{the other options}}$$

There is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ probability that you stay in place (get the same integer), and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ probability that you advance to the same possibilities as if you would have been in position $n-1$.

This gives $$e_n = e_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}$$ and along with $e_1 =2$ you get $$e_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: Ah well I'm not too surprised this kind of question had been asked at one point considering how simple it seems. Interesting nonetheless, thanks.